# Adding / Editing / Deleting columns in Entity Framework with a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, telerik

I have been working with Entity Framework for a while now and can't figure out how to do this. I remember a trick I did in the past to add a column to a table in SQL with a foreign key. Ultimately I believe I need to pass another parameter in from the SQL `summary_table` because the `ID` is different with multiple of the same `dealer_code` but different `segments` and its just picking an `ID`. I have the save in a Telerik RadWindow pop-up is there a way to possible pass a parameter from the table where the button is clicked and the pop up displays?  Just a little advice would be helpful at this point, the project is due in 2 days and I have a lot more EF to code in behind.

```
try
{
    using (WST_BusinessPlanEntities ws = new WST_BusinessPlanEntities())
    {
        //var marketAction = (from a in ws.market_segments_action_plan 
        //      join b in ws.market_segments_summary on a.ms_summary_id equals b.ms_summary_id 
        //      where b.dealer_code  ==  dealerCode
        //      select a).FirstOrDefault();

        var segmententered = (from a in ws.market_segments_action_plan
                              join b in ws.market_segments_summary on a.ms_summary_id equals b.ms_summary_id
                              where b.dealer_code == dealerCode & a.ms_summary_id == b.ms_summary_id
                              select b.ms_summary_id).SingleOrDefault();

        var msp = new market_segments_action_plan
                    {
                        //market_segments_summary mspp = null;
                        corp_conf_trade_show = chkConference.Checked,
                        corp_conf_trade_show_text = txtConference.Text,
                        corp_ride_n_drive = chkRideDrive.Checked,
                        corp_district_brand_meetings = chkDistrict.Checked,
                        corp_district_brand_meetings_text = txtDistrict.Text,
                        corp_star_days_events = chkStarDay.Checked,
                        corp_order_demo_trucks = chkOrderDemo.Checked,

                        dealer_voc_specific_event = chkVocation.Checked,
                        dealer_active_assoc_memberships = chkAssiciation.Checked,
                        dealer_active_st_trucking_assoc = chkActivePart.Checked,
                        dealer_active_local_councils = chkLocalCouncils.Checked,
                        dealer_customer_events = chkCustEvent.Checked,
                        dealer_dealership_activities = chkLocalActivities.Checked,
                        dealer_open_houses = chkMktOpenHouse.Checked,
                        dealer_open_houses_text = txtMktOpenHouse.Text,
                        dealer_billboard_program = chkBillboard.Checked,
                        dealer_conf_trade_show = chkLocalTrade.Checked,
                        dealer_dealership_activities_text = txtDealerActivities.Text,
                    };

        //msp.market_segments_summary = segmententered;
        ws.market_segments_action_plan.Add(msp);
        ws.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Means that you want to pass a parameter from html page to controller action when a button is clicked.?

Comment: Pass a parameter to Telerik Modal that is in an asp:table so when they enter the necessary data and click the "Save" button I will have that parameter but Ive gotten an error trying to use the CommandArgument with CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "segment") %>' Telerik doesn't like the DataItem? And then there is the Entity Frame work issue...on why it isn't saving correctly...I hope this helps sorry I wasn't more specific.